# Erro ao criar filtro Django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando criar um filtro, mas recebo o erro: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

msm se eu usar o related_name antes do atributo n funciona.

```
class VersoesPublicadasList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
        get:
        Retorna uma lista de todas as publicações
    """
    queryset = VersoesPublicadas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VersoesPublicadasSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['publicacoes_empresas_pb_nome']
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

[image: erro]

Comment: Poste o código de onde você esta aplicando o filtro.

Comment: Postado o trecho do codigo, @AugustoA

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) do **Django REST Framework**, você deve passar os parâmetros dentro de uma tupla ao invés de uma lista, ou seja:

```
filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
search_fields = ('publicacoes_empresas_pb_nome',)
```

Comment: Consegui resolver.

Comment: filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['publicacoes__nome', 'publicacoes__numero_versao', 'publicacoes__data_publicacao']